# How to sharpen a image in android?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, graphics

I want to sharpen a image, my code is given below:

```
 public Bitmap RuiHuaBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    int width, height;
    height = bitmap.getHeight();
    width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int red, green, blue;
    int a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9;
    Bitmap bmpBlurred = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,bitmap.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpBlurred);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    for (int i = 1; i < width - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < height - 1; j++) {

            a1 = bitmap.getPixel(i - 1, j - 1);
            a2 = bitmap.getPixel(i - 1, j);
            a3 = bitmap.getPixel(i - 1, j + 1);
            a4 = bitmap.getPixel(i, j - 1);
            a5 = bitmap.getPixel(i, j);
            a6 = bitmap.getPixel(i, j + 1);
            a7 = bitmap.getPixel(i + 1, j - 1);
            a8 = bitmap.getPixel(i + 1, j);
            a9 = bitmap.getPixel(i + 1, j + 1);

            red = (Color.red(a1) + Color.red(a2) + Color.red(a3) + Color.red(a4) + Color.red(a6) + Color.red(a7) + Color.red(a8) + Color.red(a9)) *(-1)   + Color.red(a5)*9 ;
            green = (Color.green(a1) + Color.green(a2) + Color.green(a3) + Color.green(a4) + Color.green(a6) + Color.green(a7) + Color.green(a8) + Color.green(a9)) *(-1)  + Color.green(a5)*9 ;
            blue = (Color.blue(a1) + Color.blue(a2) + Color.blue(a3) + Color.blue(a4) + Color.blue(a6) + Color.blue(a7) + Color.blue(a8) + Color.blue(a9)) *(-1)   + Color.blue(a5)*9 ;

            bmpBlurred.setPixel(i, j, Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
        }
    }
    return bmpBlurred;
}
```

but I cannot get the ideal effect. Can someone give more clue, or tell me what is mistake in my code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing range checking on the rgb values passed to Color.rgb(); you need to normalize rgb values in the [0..255] range before calling Color.rgb() method:

> public static int rgb (int red, int green, int blue) Since: API Level
>   1
>
> Return a color-int from red, green, blue components. The alpha
>   component is implicity 255 (fully opaque). These component values
>   should be [0..255], **but there is no range check performed, so if they
>   are out of range, the returned color is undefined**. Parameters red   Red
>   component [0..255] of the color green     Green component [0..255] of the
>   color blue    Blue component [0..255] of the color

Your convolution matrix seems good for a shapen transformation:

```
 0  0  0  0  0  
 0 -1 -1 -1  0
 0 -1  9 -1  0
 0 -1 -1 -1  0 
 0  0  0  0  0
```

if you think your effect is too strong, you could also try with:

```
 0  0  0  0  0  
 0  0 -1  0  0
 0 -1  5 -1  0
 0  0 -1  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0
```

as an alternative

Comment: can you tell me how to do range checking?

Comment: if (red > 255) {
     red = 255;
    } else if (red < 0) {
     red = 0;
    }

    if (green > 255) {
     green = 255;
    } else if (green < 0) {
     green = 0;
    }

    if (blue > 255) {
     blue = 255;
    } else if (blue < 0) {
     blue = 0;
    } i need add the above code?

Comment: yep I meant that; or just *red = red & 0xFF; blue = blue & 0xFF; green = green & 0xFF*

Comment: can i ask how do we implement the 5x5 matrix on a ColorMatrix?

Answer (score 0):

```
 red = (Color.red(a1) + (Color.red(a2))*(-1) + Color.red(a3) + 
       (Color.red(a4))*(-1) + (Color.red(a6))*(-1) + Color.red(a7) + 
       (Color.red(a8))*(-1) + Color.red(a9))    + Color.red(a5)*5 ;
 if(red < 0 )
    red = 0;
 if(red > 255)
    red = 255;

green = (Color.green(a1) + (Color.green(a2)) *(-1) + Color.green(a3) + 
        (Color.green(a4)) *(-1) + (Color.green(a6))*(-1) + Color.green(a7) + 
        (Color.green(a8))*(-1) + Color.green(a9)) + Color.green(a5)*5 ;
if(green < 0 )
    green = 0;
if(green > 255)
    green = 255;

blue = (Color.blue(a1) + (Color.blue(a2))*(-1) + Color.blue(a3) + 
       (Color.blue(a4))*(-1) + (Color.blue(a6))*(-1) + Color.blue(a7) + 
       (Color.blue(a8)) *(-1) + Color.blue(a9))   + Color.blue(a5)*5 ;
if(blue < 0 )
    blue = 0;
if(blue > 255)
    blue = 255;
```