# how to increase image sharpness with out losing it's colors by using android opencv

Tags: android

**i am increasing image sharpness by using fallowing code**

```
Mat source = Imgcodecs.imread(path, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

Mat destination=newMat(source.rows(),source.cols(),source.type());

Imgproc.GaussianBlur(source, destination, new Size(0,0), 10);

Core.addWeighted(source, 2.5, destination, -0.5, 0, destination);

bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source.cols(),
destination.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Utils.matToBitmap(destination, bitmap);

image_view2.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

it is displaying some quality image but displayed image is only black & white, lost it's original colors

but I need to display the original colour

How to do it?
Thank's for helping

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980418/how-to-sharpen-a-image-in-android

Comment: Thank for reply,but using open cv methods not an android